# confusion in using YII CHtml::link and CHtml::image instead of HTML

Tags: yii

I have started an application in YII, I want to use proper standards of YII but am just bit curious about the use of its CHTML Class. I think that using `CHtml::link()` or `CHtml::image()` instead of normal HTML code `<a></a>` and `<img src... />` will cost more time to application on server side. I tried to look for some reason to use it but yet not success in finding any good resource on why should I use it and how its beneficial then traditional HTML. Like I can use all those methods for defining paths to actions in normal HTML code then why use it

any help or reference for clarification would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: i usually use chtml in combination with model and form, in such way you have all your values auto-filled, etc.

Comment: thanks for reply, I am actually working on site navigation menus right now which has nothing to do with models just html links over images are there, so do you think plain html would work fine here ? and chtml for transactional forms and links only?

Comment: i'm not a pro in yii and using it not long ago, but yes, i'm using plain html in most situations like you described and use chtml just for forms, and maybe some other cases, can't recall examples now, sorry. lets wait for answers, maybe someone has more to tell

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's talk about CHtml::link(). Its main advantage is that you can indicate a controller route and send some get variables by simply passing an array as paramater. Lets say you wanna go to the eat() action of your LivingController, with the variable 'meal' and its value being 'hamburgers'. It could simply be done like this:

```
> CHtml::link(array('LivingController/eat', 'meal'=>'hamburgers'));
```

If you want to express this using `<a></a>` only, then I don't need to tell you how much harder it would be. In addition, we should remember that a link generated using CHtml::link() will always work, even if you change the url format. That wouldn't happen with `<a></a>`: you would have to rewrite the url every time you change the url format.

The advantages of CHtml::image() are less clear, at least to me. Sincerely, I think it's just a matter of encapsulation.

Comment: oh yes! making sense to me now URL formatting got it. Developers of YII were not so stupid actually to waste their time over these classes; they are absolutely of use. Thanks ACG for clarification :) appreciated!

Comment: i use create url for creating links http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#createUrl-detail it does same work, that's why i can't remember why i need chtml::link 8)

Comment: Yeah, but createUrl() does not create a link. Actually, createUrl() is used by CHtml::link(), trough CHtml::normalizeUrl().

Comment: yeah, i mean i use it for creating url inside link `<a href="<? ...createUrl(...)... ?>">`

Comment: Might want to modify the above code like so:
CHtml::link('Awesome Link Text',array('LivingController/eat', 'meal'=>'hamburgers'));